# TFS workItem.Validate() issue

Tags: tfs

Here is the case. I wrote a tool to create a task WorkItem (version 12.0.0.0), it can run normally and create TFS task last month. But Today, when I rerun it, it doesn't create TFS task and show error message: The field "Assigned To" contains the value "email address" that is not in the list of supported values.

```
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer = new TfsConfigurationServer(tfsUri, credential);
ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> collectionNodes = configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection }, false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);
foreach (CatalogNode collectionNode in collectionNodes)
        {
            Guid collectionId = new Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
            TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);
            ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> projectNodes = collectionNode.QueryChildren(new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.TeamProject }, false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);
            foreach (CatalogNode projectNode in projectNodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Team Project: " + projectNode.Resource.DisplayName);
            }
            WorkItemStore workstore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
            Project project = workstore.Projects["SpecifiedProject"];
            WorkItemType itemtype = project.WorkItemTypes["Task"];

            WorkItem workItem = new WorkItem(itemtype);

            string assignedTo;
            assignedTo = String.Format("{0}@***.com", task.User);
            workItem.Fields["Assigned to"].Value = assignedTo;

            workItem.Fields["Priority"].Value = task.Priority;
            workItem.Fields["Area Path"].Value = AREAPATH;
            workItem.Fields["Iteration path"].Value = task.IterationPath;
            workItem.Title = task.Title;

            workItem.Fields["DESCRIPTION"].Value = task.Description;
            workItem.Fields["Original Estimate"].Value = task.EstimatedTime.ToString();
            workItem.Fields["Completed Work"].Value = task.ActualTime.ToString();
            workItem.Fields["Remaining Work"].Value = task.RemainTime.ToString();
            // get the link type for hierarchical relationships
            var linkType = workstore.WorkItemLinkTypes[CoreLinkTypeReferenceNames.Hierarchy];
            //var linkType = workstore.WorkItemLinkTypes[CoreLinkTypeReferenceNames.Dependency];
            RelatedLink rl = new RelatedLink(linkType.ReverseEnd, task.UserStoryID);
            workItem.Links.Add(rl);
            ArrayList ValidationResult = workItem.Validate();
```

I think this code block "ArrayList ValidationResult = workItem.Validate();" has some issues, for detail error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCfpQ.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure that the user still exists in your AD? The error message is indicating that the user can't be found.

Comment: Like Daniel said, go to TFS and try to create manually a task and put this email in the Assigned To field, did you success?